# WCF EndpointNotFoundException when running as NetworkService

Tags: c#, wcf, net.pipe

I have a net.Pipe WCF service that is hosted by IIS (right now, in my VS2010):
(Global.asax):

```
 protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

  WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

  ServiceHost svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DoSomethingService), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/helloworld"));
  var serviceBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding { MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue, MaxConnections = 2048 };
  var sect = new NamedPipeTransportSecurity { ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign };
  var sec = new NetNamedPipeSecurity { Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.Transport, Transport = sect };
  serviceBinding.Security = sec;

  svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDoSomethingContract), serviceBinding, "");
  svcHost.Open();
}
```

I have a console app client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var factory = new ChannelFactory<IDoSomethingContract>();

  var defaultCredentials = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
  factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials); 
  factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
  factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  var serviceBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding { MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue, MaxConnections = 2048 };
  var sect = new NamedPipeTransportSecurity { ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign };
  var sec = new NetNamedPipeSecurity { Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.Transport, Transport = sect };
  serviceBinding.Security = sec;
  var ep = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/helloworld");
  factory.Endpoint.Binding = serviceBinding;
  var love = factory.CreateChannel(ep); 
  Console.WriteLine(love.Do());

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Now everything works great when I run this as a user principal (and so I can use a PrincipalPermission inside my operation).

However, if I create myself a 'Network Service' command line prompt (using psexec), and try to run the client (with the service running, obviously), I get the EndpointNotFoundException exception.

Is there anything I need to do for Network Service to see my named pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was considering deleting this, but since somebody actually commented - I found the answer here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fcb7254a-15b5-4be4-bf67-34d500bdce2d/wcf-netpipe-endpoint-not-found-exception-whitout-elevated-user-rights-uac-enabled?forum=wcf

Basically, since I was running my dev server as my own account, the service was published in Session namespace. Once I published this on real IIS as Network Service, it was visible in the Global Namespace, so I could see it.

Answer (score 1):

May be following articles useful for you

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/asp-net/developing-a-wcf-service-library-and-hosting-it-as-wcf-web-service-using-vs2k8/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx